# How to convert a string into a DateTime (formatted D/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS PM)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How would I convert two strings like this into a DateTime in javascript so that I can compare them (find out if one is an earlier date than the other)

```
7/10/2015 12:46:00 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Date()` method accepts a string value which it will parse to a date. From there you can compare using the standard `<` or `>` operators. Try this:

```js
var date1 = new Date('7/10/2015 12:46:00 PM');
var date2 = new Date('6/9/2014 11:45:00 PM');

if (date2 < date1) 
    alert('date2 is before date1');
```